# Data Lost after scroll in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios6, plist

I am trying to display plist data in tableview.

My problem is that after scrolling down i lost my previously fetched data.
Actually i am using custom cell so i think this is happen.

Code for Source and delegate of table is below.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *kCellID = @"Cell";

OffersCustomCell *cell = (OffersCustomCell *)[mytableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
if (cell == nil)
{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OffersList" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OffersCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];



    cell.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Formata-Regular" size:13.0f];
    cell.saveLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Formata-Bold" size:14.0f];
    cell.nowLabel.font = cell.titleLabel.font;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}



NSDictionary *dict = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);


cell.titleLabel.text = [dict  objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.nowLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"price"];
cell.saveLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"rondel"];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       [mytableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. :)

only problem is no retaining memory for UItableview.

```
 tableData = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[dic objectForKey:@"Response"], nil] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the height for each cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat height = 0;
    //calculate height for each cell

    return height;
}
```

Use this UITableView delegate method to set height of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

you can use another class that is store your data and reload time you used that class and restore your data correctly and efficiently.